# SELECT DISTINCT query taking too long SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, query-optimization, distinct

This is my code below, it's taking a very a long time to execute. When I add the SELECT DISTINCT it makes it very  long.

What I'm trying to do is get unique companies that satisfy these conditions and also calculate how many teams each company has (this is given by team_id which is given to each user in auth_user u table).

Any help would be amazing, I want to learn how to make better SQL queries. I know that GROUP BY is the better way to do this, but I can't seem to get it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.company_id, c.name, c.company_type, c.office_location, (SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT u.team_id)) FROM auth_user u WHERE u.company_id = c.id GROUP BY u.company_id) as number_of_teams, s.status, h.auto_renewal
FROM auth_user u, companies_company c, subscriptions_subscription s, hubspot_company h
    WHERE u.company_id = c.id
        AND s.company_id = c.id
        AND h.myagi_id = c.id
ORDER BY u.company_id ASC
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!  (However, no performance difference.)

Comment: "modern JOIN syntax" is over 30 years old

Comment: No need for the GROUP BY in the subquery, just make sure it still is correlated.

Comment: Do you even need SELECT DISTINCT? Will any duplicate rows be eliminated?

Comment: `get unique companies that satisfy these conditions` <<-- in that case, only companies should be in the FROM clause of the main query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all refactor your query to use the 1992 JOIN syntax instead of your grandpa's comma-join syntax. (I'm a grandpa and I jumped at using JOIN as soon as it became available.)

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT u.company_id, c.name, c.company_type, c.office_location, 
       count_of_teams_TODO,
       s.status, h.auto_renewal
  FROM auth_user u
  JOIN companies_company c ON u.company_id = c.id
  JOIN subscriptions_subscription s ON  s.company_id = c.id
  JOIN hubspot_company h ON h.myagi_id = c.id
 ORDER BY u.company_id ASC;
```

Then, I believe each user belongs to one team; that is has one value of `auth_user.team_id`.   And you want your result set to show how many teams the company has.

So substitute `COUNT(DISTINCT u.team_id) teams` for my `count_of_teams_TODO` placeholder, getting this. There's no need for a subquery. But for the aggregate function `COUNT()` we need `GROUP BY`. And we want to group by company, status, and autorenewal.

```sql
SELECT c.id, company_id, c.name, c.company_type, c.office_location, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT u.team_id) teams,
       s.status, h.auto_renewal
  FROM auth_user u
  JOIN companies_company c ON u.company_id = c.id
  JOIN subscriptions_subscription s ON  s.company_id = c.id
  JOIN hubspot_company h ON h.myagi_id = c.id
 GROUP BY c.id, s.status, h.auto_renewal
 ORDER BY u.company_id ASC;
```

And that should do it.  Study up on `GROUP BY` and aggregate functions. Every second you spend learning those concepts better will help you.

As far as performance goes, get this working and then ask another question. Tag it with [query-optimization](/questions/tagged/query-optimization) and [read this before you ask it](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info).

Comment: On Sept 25th 2014 Mysql 5.7.5. was released with the default 'ONLY FULL GROUP BY'. You seem to be a MySQL user, because your query does not take into account this setting?  (And the question is about postgresql, which has this by default)

Comment: That's why I changed the first column in SELECT to the primary key of the companies table. The other columns from that table are dependent on the pk.

Comment: OK, it seems to be correct... (see: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158015/why-can-i-select-all-fields-when-grouping-by-primary-key-but-not-when-grouping-b )

Comment: Yeah, good catch. I don't think including all the columns in the `GROUP BY`, rather than just the PK, causes any trouble, though.